# Best way to manage old data in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, delete

I have a postgres db where everyday a significant number of rows across multiple tables are considered outdated and soft deleted. My understanding is that there's no point in keeping these rows around and it would be better to remove them on a regular basis (example once a week) to get the best performance out of my db. Which leads me to my first question:

1. Am I right to think that deleting unused rows will result in the best performance over time or is that bit naive?

If the answer is yes, the problem is that the delete process can be very very slow due to the size of the delete and the constraints between tables. I'm unable to get superuser privileges to do stuff like disabling all triggers or changing `session_replication_role`.

The other option I have is to drop my constraints and recreate them but this seems risky since my constraints are automatically generated using [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) and it would seem like a matter of time until a change in my schema would result in these going out of sync causing some issues I'd much rather avoid.

2. Is there some way I have missed to easily disable the constraints and re-enable them without being a superuser?

Comment: If the tables where you want to get rid of the rows aren't _referenced_ by other tables, you can consider partitioning. Then getting rid of the rows is quite fast as you only need to drop the (old) partitions. Sadly, Postgres doesn't support foreign keys _referencing_ partitioned tables, so if you need that, this isn't an option.

Comment: Yeh I do have foreign key constraints between tables so I guess that means it’s not an option to do that. If I didn’t have the foreign keys I think the delete would be pretty fast anyway so not sure if there’s a benefit to doing it using partitions in that case.

Comment: Dropping (or simply detaching) a partition takes a few **milli**seconds (regardless of the size of the partition).  That will always be substantially faster than any DELETE statement.

Comment: soft deletes are usually a poisoned chalice.  Can't you just have a tested PITR strategy and then actually delete rows when you want to delete them?  How often do you have to resurrect soft-deleted rows?

Comment: Why does it need to be fast?

Comment: Doesn’t need to be fast but doing a normal delete will take hours if not days to complete. Don’t care if takes 10 seconds or 10 milliseconds though. I need it to be under a minute because my app is serverless and the serverless function time out after 1 minute.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You can have a foreign key referencing a partitioned table. But the you won't be able to detach partitions any more.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: but only if the partition key is part of the primary key, right? Which typically isn't the case in such a situation - at least in my experience.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree, it is often not feasible to define primary keys on partitioned tables. I just couldn't let your claim stand: "Sadly, Postgres doesn't support foreign keys *referencing* partitioned tables".

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: OK, fair enough

Comment: Thanks for you help, in the end I decided to drop my foreign key constraints altogether as my database only has a single client and I can manage these constraints from there.